# Javascript Edit-Delete Function from a looped Textbox with Values

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am new to web development and I am trying to add an add/edit/delete function to my displayed form values using Javascript. Well, I cant really find the words to explain but this is what Im trying to accomplish.

I have this loop that lists discounts from a database:

```
@foreach (var discount in Model.Discounts)
            {
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="@discount.Key.DiscountCode">@discount.Key.DiscountName</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="@discount.Key.DiscountCode" name="@discount.Key.DiscountCode" readonly="true" type="text" />
                    <a class="remove" data-key="@discount.Key.DiscountCode" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a>
                    <a class="edit" data-key="@discount.Key.DiscountCode" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</a>
                </div> <br />
            }

<a class="add-discount"  href="javascript:void(0);">Add Discount</a>
```

As you can imagine this will loop into this kind of output:

Label1 [Textbox for Label1] Delete Edit 
Label2 [Textbox for Label2] Delete Edit 
Label3 [Textbox for Label3] Delete Edit

How can I make these commands work using javascript/jquery. 
Please note that the delete/edit function only applies to the displayed data and not the database. what I meant is if I click Delete, it will delete its corresponding Label and Textbox from the display only and not in the database, also when Edit is clicked, it will only enable the textbox to alter the data inside it. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!!


I am using Visual Studio 2013 and developing this using ASP.NET MVC4 

**Follow up:** 
I was wondering how can I automatically compute the total value of the textboxes and display it in a Total Discount textbox. 
Please note the Edit and Delete function of my list should affect the total when I edit, or delete a discount. 
I have tried to search for the solution but all I see have fixed texboxes with class name each unlike mine that has indefinite amount of textboxes looped from a database. 
 Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following JQuery functions to Remove/Edit, and also to change the text while editing to have it make more sense:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var input = parent.find('input');

    if (input.attr('readonly') === 'readonly') {
        $(this).text('Stop Edit');
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('Edit');
    }
    input.attr('readonly', !input.attr('readonly'));       
});

$('.remove').on('click', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest("div");
    var uncle = parent.prev();
    parent.remove();
    uncle.remove();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25bu53z4/2/)

Comment: Oh wow thank you boss! This is the one im looking for, the only problem I have is it only removes my textbox because the label is on a separate <div> is there a way I to work around this without me using a single <div> for both the label and the textbox?

Comment: @super-maynard Here ya go, updated the fiddle and the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/25bu53z4/2/

Comment: Thank you Omri that did the trick. As I can see you really know how to work JQuery can I abuse your kindness a little have a follow up question here. Or maybe I'll make another question and link it here, its about adding a new textbox that shows the total of all my looped textbox. EDIT: By total I meant SUM of the discount textboxes(has float values)

Comment: @super-maynard Post a new question, you can link it here I'll try to take a look :)

Comment: Hi Omri I tried to post a new question but it says that I have to wait 90 mins and Im afraid i wont be able to catch you again 90mins from now as I needed to finish this until tonight I'd like to detail it here in this question, what I wanted to accomplish is.. (question updated)

Comment: Hi Omri thank you again, this worked but what if the class name of the looped textboxes are based on the discount code. In my example I made the class name to "discountCode" which is static, but actually it is "@Model.discount.discountCode" so each textboxes will have unique class name of their own. The javascript wont work because it only uses the static class name "discountCode", is there a way to this?

Comment: I added a new question regarding this followup, I hope you could help me again, thank you. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737885/javascript-jquery-textbox-values-calculations

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("a.remove").on("click", function() {
     $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });

   $("a.edit").on("click", function(){
     $(this).siblings("input").prop("readonly",false).focus();
   });
});
```

You can try with above code `.remove()` will remove the element node and for edit make the `readonly` property `false` to make input element editable.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73s5jfzb/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help but I cant make it work with this, I think because the 'e' is not defined in my document, as I am new I don't really know where to put it.

Comment: @super-maynard try declaring e inside click function like this`$("a.edit").on("click", function(e){` you can refer the demo also