# Javascript/JQuery Textbox Values Calculations

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, textbox

I was trying to make a simple computation out of these textboxes.

This is my code so far:

```
   @foreach (var discount in Model.Discounts)
            {
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="@discount.Key.DiscountCode">@discount.Key.DiscountName</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="discountCode" name="discountCode" readonly="true" type="text" />
                    <a class="remove" data-key="discountCode" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a>
                    <a class="edit" data-key="discountCode" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</a>
                </div> <br />
            }

<div class="totaldiscounts">
Total: <input id="total" type="text" />
</div>

    <script>
    $('.edit').on('click', function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var input = parent.find('input');

        if (input.attr('readonly') === 'readonly') {
            $(this).text('Stop Edit');
        }
        else {
            $(this).text('Edit');
        }
        input.attr('readonly', !input.attr('readonly'));


    });

    $('.remove').on('click', function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var input = parent.find('input');
        input[0].value = 0;
        $(input).first().blur();

        var parent = $(this).closest("div");
        var uncle = parent.prev();
        parent.remove();
        uncle.remove();
    });


    $('.discountCode').on('blur', function () {

        var inputs = $(".discountCode");

        var val = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(inputs[i].value)) {
                val += +inputs[i].value; 
            }
        }

        $('#total').val(val);
    });
    </script>
```

This code works until I have to change the class name of each textboxes into their actual unique discount codes like this:

```
<input class="@Model.discount.discountCode" name="@Model.discount.discountCode" readonly="true" type="text" />
```

So apparently, my javascript no longer works because the classname of each textboxes are now different to each other. 
How can I make my javascript work with this setup.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: You can set the additional class name into the textbox(with the same class name), and loop over it.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Hi, sorry im new to development, from what I understand you are telling me to put 2 class names in a single element, is this right or if not can you elaborate. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, put the another class name with same class name. can you?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali can you show me a simple example of using 2 class names because the way I do it is ridiculous. lol.

Comment: first of all, i did't know how to add class name using c#, but normally i'm using something like this `class="unique_class_name shared_class_name"`

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali hi boss! nevermind, I think I did it. Thank you for your help, would you mind putting an answer in this question so I can select it as the answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the additional class name into element(example).

```
class="unique_class_name shared_class_name"
```

After all, loop to each class(shared_class_name), to get the value like following code :

```
$('.shared_class_name').on('blur', function ()....
```